# Remove special characters from a url, but not other language characters

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a web application where people post articles(like forum) in english and other languages. To create pretty permalinks from post title I use code like this.

**PHP:**

```
$ln=preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9[:space:]]/","",$name);
$ln = strtolower($ln);
$ln=str_replace(' ','-',$ln);
```

This strips all characters except alphabets and numerics. But I also want to keep words in other languages like Chinese or Hindi. So it won't stript "`स्टैक ओवरफ्लो`" to " ". I am unable to find any REGEX solution yet.

Comment: What is `$1` represents in the replacement part?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[^\p{L} 0-9]
```

`\p{L} matches any kind of letter from any language`
You can try this.This will preserve words from other languages and remove special symbols.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/qH1uG3/8

```
$re = "/[^\\p{L} 0-9]/m";
$str = "@#\$#\$sadsadस्टैक ओवरफ्लो";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

or

```
[^\p{L}\p{Z}\p{N}\p{M}]
```

- `\p{L}` matches any kind of **letter from any language**
- `\p{Z}` matches any kind of **whitespace or invisible separator**
- `\p{N}` matches any kind of **numeric character** in any script
- `\p{M}` matches a character **intended to be combined with**

To be more precise.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/qH1uG3/11

Comment: it would match digits.

Comment: Will this remove |,",",=,+,_ and all other non-url-friendly characters.

Comment: Nice regex we;l it still have some problems as you can see at regex101 but overall a nice solution.

Comment: @IdidntKnewIt now the problem is solved completely.Check the new demo.`\p{M}` was missing.Check now